AnnotationProcessor using JavaAssist fails to find class, class is not generated because annotations failed to process
I'm trying to create a custom annotation and annotation processor to modify generated classes btyecode using JavaAssist and using gradle to compile the main project and the two annotation modules.
Think something like Lombok where I can annotate a method with @Setter and it will modify the generated class to include a setter method without having to manually write the code.
This is just an attempt to get the bare basics working, I will be creating something more advanced to automate remote method invocation but I can't get this working.
I have successfully gotten the annotation processor to run however it cannot find the class files in the main project, and fails to process annotations and therefor never generates any class files in the directory its looking for them.
I suspect that means its trying to find the class files before they have been generated, and it needs to be a two stage process but I'm really not sure.
All the code for the test project is here:
https://github.com/MatthewJuliusScott/PublicRepository/tree/main/AnnotationTest but for ease of viewing here are what I hope are the relevant files:
The error:
> Task :compileJava FAILED
javassist.NotFoundException: org.example.TestModel
    at javassist.ClassPool.get(ClassPool.java:430)

org.example.TestAnnotationProcessor
@SupportedAnnotationTypes("org.example.TestAnnotation")
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_11)
public class TestAnnotationProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {
    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        for (Element element : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(TestAnnotation.class)) {
            if (element.getKind() == ElementKind.METHOD) {
                // Process the annotated setter method
                injectPrint(element);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void injectPrint(Element element) {
        try {

            processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.NOTE, "Attempting to inject print into " + element.getSimpleName());

            // Get the fully qualified class name and the method
            String className = ((TypeElement) element.getEnclosingElement()).getQualifiedName().toString();
            String methodName = element.getSimpleName().toString();

            // Load the class using Javassist
            ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
            CtClass ctClass = pool.get(className);

            // Get the setter method
            CtMethod ctMethod = ctClass.getDeclaredMethod(methodName);

            // Insert RMI logic at the start of the method
            ctMethod.insertBefore("{ System.out.println(\"This was added by a custom annotation.\"); }");

            // Write the modified class to disk (this step can vary based on your environment)
            ctClass.writeFile();

            processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.NOTE, "Successfully injected print into " + methodName);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR, e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

org.example.TestAnnotation
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface TestAnnotation {
}

And the build files:
build.gradle (test-annotation)
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group = 'org.example'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
}

build.gradle (test-annotation-processor)
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group = 'org.example'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':test-annotation')
    implementation group: 'org.javassist', name: 'javassist', version: '3.30.2-GA'
}

build.gradle (AnnotationTest)
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group = 'org.example'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':test-annotation')
    implementation group: 'org.javassist', name: 'javassist', version: '3.30.2-GA'

    annotationProcessor project(":test-annotation-processor")
}

settings.gradle (AnnotationTest)
rootProject.name = 'AnnotationTest'
include 'test-annotation-processor', 'test-annotation'

I've tried creating custom build tasks in the build.gradle files, like:
tasks.withType(JavaCompile).configureEach {
        dependsOn ':core:compileJava'
        options.annotationProcessorPath = configurations.annotationProcessor
    }

but that hasn't resolved it, the annotation processor still fails to find the generated class, which I believe fails to generate the class because annotation processing fails.

This question is similar to: How can I read CtClass from .class file?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
